# Bitmap c динамическими ресурсами

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Добрый день.

Есть ресурсы картинок `exes1`, `exes2` и тд.
Как создавать динамический `Bitmap`?
Например, я передаю 2 и мне возвращается ресурс `exes2`

Сейчас получаю картинки так:

```
Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.exes1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(int i){
    return drawableToBitmap(getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("exes" + i, "drawable", "ru.example.app"));
}

private Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```